# make server-client work unlimitedly

Tags: c#, client-server

How can I make the server and the client to run unlimitedly and be able to exchange data(meaning, until the application is closed), instead of run for one exchange of information only. 
Tried with `while(true)` but maybe didn't put it on the right place and then I can't really reach the methods for closing and stopping the socket and the listener. 
Here's some of the code of the server:

```
public static void StartServer()
        {
            try
            {
                IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.11");
                TcpListener myListener = new TcpListener(ip, 8000);

                myListener.Start();

                Socket s = myListener.AcceptSocket();

                byte[] b = new byte[100];
                int k = s.Receive(b);

... some other actions ...

                s.Close();
                myListener.Stop();
            }
```

and then then `Main()` where I invoke it. 
With the Client is the same story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an infinite loop which contains the Receive function processing data, and returns to receive. That way the server always excepts data from the client until server, or client terminates.

```
while(true)
{
       byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
       s.Receive(buffer);
       //Do something with data...
}
```

Beware through because in your current design only one client is supported. If you want to support multiple clients consider using threads.